# How to use verilog to blink an led

Tags: verilog, vivado

I have been trying to make a blinking led in Verilog using vivado. I have a 100MHz FPGA. My code is posted below:

```
module Blinky(
input clk,
input reset,
output reg led
);


reg [26:0] count; 
wire state;
assign state = count[26];

always@ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
 begin
  if (reset)
   count <= 0;  
  else
   count <= count + 1;  //otherwise increment the register
  end

always@ (posedge state)
    if (led == 1'b1)
        led = 1'b0;
    else
        led = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

in this code I am attempting to use a clock divider to slow down the clock. I then used the slowed clock signal to switch the led on and off. I know the constraints are correct because I can hard-code the led to go on and off. But when I try this or variations of it nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: Complete lack of functionality usually points to something simple.  Make sure your clock is actually running (connected to the correct pin for an external clock source) and that your reset is correctly connected.  Synchronize your reset pin.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. The topmost bit of the counter can be used to drive the LED directly; you don't need to use it as a clock to a separate flip-flop. (Generally speaking, you should use as few separate clock signals as possible in FPGA designs; the FPGA routing fabric only supports a small number of global clocks.)

Change `output reg led` to `output led`, remove `state` and everything referencing it (including the entirety of the second `always` block), and add:

```
assign led = count[26];
```

Comment: thanks for the help. it seems like it should work, but it still does nothing.